# php strange outputs before <!doctype>

Tags: php, html, doctype

I have the following pages.

index.php

```
<?php
require('configure.php');
?>
```

configure.php

```
<?php
die();
?>
```

The above outputs a "-" (dash) when i copy it, it looks as if it's a new line or something of that nature. Its the first time i get this kind of behaviour.

The problem stands that if anything is before the  the browser does not render the source properly.

any one come across this?

Comment: Can you show what exactly gets rendered?

Comment: I cn't because it looks empty in firefox and a dash in chrome, when i copy the source to notepad it looks like the dash is actually a newline.

Comment: also i have used notepad, and the encoding was on ASCII so i changed it to utf8 and still same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be saving your file as UTF-8. Save it as 'UTF-8 without BOM' or ASCII and the problem will be solved.

The 'Byte order mark' in UTF-8 encoding creates the problem. Use any good editor like Notepad++ and change the encoding of the files.

Comment: thank you :) that seems to be the problem the weird thing was that it was initially on ASCII and i don't know why that problem started. hopefully it will solve my problem with the <script> and <link> as they appeard on the body on firebug and on head on the source